# check if selected option and checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have some problems here with javascript.
I want someone to choose an option and a checked box, and if both are checked then other checkboxes should not be able to click.
I had tried to give the function 2 parameters (one is for the option and one for the checkbox).

```
function bs(id /*,chbxvalue */ )
{
    var selectElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var selectValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;

    //var select2Element = document.getElementById(chbxvalue);
    //var selectCHBXval = select2Element.options[select2Element.selectedIndex].value;

    if((selectValue == "banana" ) /*&& (document.getElementById("apple").checked == true )*/ )
    {
        document.getElementById("juice").checked = true;
    }
    else if(selectValue == "Salad")
    {}
}
```

The thing in the comments doesn't work.

```
<div id="flavor"><br />
  <select id="bss" name="beh" onChange="bs('bss')">
     <option value="banana" >banana</option>
     <option value="pinapple" >pinapple</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="divcontainer" class="cont" style="display:block;">
       <input type="checkbox" name="app" id="apple" value="appl" />Apples <br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="juices" id="juice" value="fj" />Fruitjuice <br />
</div>
```

I've changed the names here. Has anybody an idea? Sorry, I am not so good with javascript... .

Comment: Is this a typo `var selectValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex.]value;` ?

Comment: I think it should be `var selectValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: `document.getElementsById()` is a non-existent function, notice the 's' in the method-call. You need to use a singular, because there must only ever be *one* element with a given `id`; so it should be `getElementById()` (remove the 's' character).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd like to use simply

```
document.getElementById("...").disabled=true;
```

Or if you'd like to disable more checkboxes at once, assign them a class, and use

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
{elements[i].disabled = "true"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're after, but it seems like you want some kind of conditional logic. I made a fiddle to illustrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/75uLereo/

```
var radios = document.myform.type,
    select = document.myform.flavor;

for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', checkValues);
}

select.addEventListener('change', checkValues);


function checkValues(){
    var select = document.myform.flavor,
    selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value,
    radioValue = document.querySelector('input[name = "type"]:checked').value;

    if(radioValue !== "undefined"){    
      switch(selectedValue){
        case 'none':
        case 'banana':
        case 'strawberry':
            alert("This is "+selectedValue+" and "+radioValue+". Do some conditional logic with the values!");
          break;
        default:
        break;
      }
   }

}
```

This binds a function to change events on the radio buttons and the select and then uses a switch on the different values to do whatever you want it to do.

**Updated:**

I made another example, with checkboxes and the bool value from the checkboxes if they are selected

https://jsfiddle.net/75uLereo/2/

Comment: Okay, it's the same logic for checkboxes (didn't see that you had checkboxes in the question), but I still don't know exactly what you're after. If you could give a better description, I can give a better explanation and example.

Comment: I did a updated answer with a fiddle above, try checking it out.

Comment: Okay. But at least this addresses the issue you where having with the .checked. In this example you can clearly see the bool if-statement working, like you asked about, so at least you can get that working. I'm still not sure whether or not you're just trying to have someone doing all the work for you, but good luck at least!

Comment: You should seriously consider reading up on javascript before taking a task like that. I really dummied it down for you now, but I can't do anymore, than this: https://jsfiddle.net/gbc363Le/